# Title has unwanted indent in it

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I don't know what went wrong but it seems my chapter title has indent in it. Anyone can help me understand why it happens?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\flushleft}{\thechapter}{0pt}{\Large\flushleft}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit saghittar. Nullam sagittis quis mauris eget tempor?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are abusing `\flushleft`, which is actually the internal macro for the *environment* of the same name (meaning that `\flushleft` works as intended when there is also an `\endflushleft`, which is missing here).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge}{\thechapter}{0ex}{\Large\raggedright}
%                                                   ^^^
%                        additional vertical space between chapter label and title
\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit saghittar. Nullam sagittis quis mauris eget tempor?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** As egreg remarked in his comment, the `titlesec` package suggests to use the macro `\filright` instead of `\raggedright` in the argument of `\titleformat`. `\raggedright` would kill horizontal spaces set by `\titleformat` while `\filright` doesn't. This wouldn't make a difference in this specific case but might break in other cases.

Comment: So that's why. Thank you. I get this template from someone and I'm trying to understand the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: `titlesec` suggests `\filright` instead of `\raggedright`.

Comment: @egreg Oh, right, I forgot about that. Edited, thx.